# How to detect Screen Size changes on iPad?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I detect the Screen Size change in my iPad application? An app on the iPad can be displayed in Portrait and Landscape modes, but also in Split View.

I'm thinking about observing the size with GeometryReader like:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
...
}
.onChange(of: proxy.size) { newSize in
//Size changed, react accordingly
}
```

Or use PreferenceKey:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    Color.clear.preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.size)
}
.onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { newValue in
//Size changed, react accordingly
}
```

Which option is correct? Is there a correct way?

Comment: Did you test these two? Did one or both of them work?

Answer (score 1):

There is really no right or wrong way. Both methods are perfectly fine.

That being said however, I would pick the first method of `GeometryReader` as it is more concise and easier to understand. `PreferenceKey` can get really complex and annoying to use especially as the app grows and becomes more complex.

It is worth noting however, you may want to use `PreferenceKey` if you want to propagate the size changes through a more complex view hierarchy.

You may also use `MatchedGeomtryEffect` with `GeomtryReader` if all you want to do is animations.

Remember, SwiftUI will automatically layout your views according to the available space. In many cases, SwiftUI will handle screen size changes without needing to observe and react to them explicitly.

Just a quick note however:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
...
}
.onChange(of: proxy.size) { newSize in
//Size changed, react accordingly
}
```

This is incorrect as `proxy` is undefined in `.onChange`.

You can do something like this.

```
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                ...
            }
            .onChange(of: proxy.size) { newSize in
                //Size changed, react accordingly
            }
        }
```